# PHP version shown in command line differs from phpinfo(); in localhost:8000

Tags: macos, php

I started my OS X PHP test server by typing

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

I updated my PHP on OS X to 5.6 and when I check the version through the command line by typing:

```
php -v
```

It tells me that I have "PHP 5.6.5"

When I start my PHP test server and look at the index.php file that has the `phpinfo();` function, it tells me that I still have version 5.5.14 that comes with OS X.

What can I do to get my PHP version on localhost:8000 to reflect that change?

Comment: Where did you install the updated PHP and what is your current $PATH? (type `echo $PATH` in Terminal). It sounds like the $PATH isn't set up to find the new version of PHP.

Comment: I installed to "/usr/local".   When I checked the path with "echo $PATH" I saw "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin".   I deleted the Server App recently. Should I export the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of PHP needs to be in your $PATH and the path to the new version of php needs to be listed before `/usr/bin`. If the new version of php (the executable) is installed in `/usr/local/bin/` you should be in good shape, otherwise you need to either  link the new php executable there (`ln -s /path/to/newphp /usr/local/bin/php`) or add it's location to your $PATH (`export PATH=/path/to/newphp:"${PATH}"`) (<- add this to your ~/.bash_profile).

One other possibility to check... is the new version of php named `php`? It's possible that it will be named something like `php5` or some such thing. If so you'll need to create a a link or use that name on the command line.

Comment: Well, I upgrade to PHP 7 in `/usr/local/bin/` but my version remains in 5.6.24. The installer created a php5 alias and I created a php alias manually. But both `<?php phpinfo();?>` and `php -v` tells me I am using the old one. And I tried `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/php5-7.0.11-20160923-203451:"${PATH}"` too.

Comment: @JamesWayne Try export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH

Comment: Whoa there... First, that path statement is all wrong... where is the newest version of PHP installed (how did you install it)? Knowing this, I can help you on the command line (assuming it's all installed correctly). Second, after updating PHP did you reconfigure your web server to use the new version of PHP?